# How to calculate the probability value of multiple probabilities

Tags: probability

The question arises from baffled curiosity. I have consulted stats textbooks, e.g. Agresti & Franklin, Statistics, but don't know which heading to look under. My precise question is this. Suppose an event, X, is witnessed by five independent witnesses the relability of each of whose testimony is <.5. Say : .2, .3. .3. 4. .4. I have a sense - excuse my naivety - that the combination of these probabilities, given the independence of the witnesses, could be = .5 or >.5.

I'd appreciate someone's doing the calculation for me and (so that I can make my own headway) directing me to the relevant area of stats. My interests are legal and historical. But I sure need some maths help.

Comment: So you want something like "What is the probability the event occurred, given the reliability of each individual"? Sorry I didn't quite understand what you want.

Comment: @Tony Hellmuth. Thanks for comment. You have the point exactly. The probability of each independent witness' testimony is >.5. I wondered if the joint probability of the independent witnesses' testimony was higher than .4. Best : GT

Comment: Well it does depend on how you define the event that a witness is reliable. Say if $Y_i=1$  if witness i was right and  $Y_i=0$ if witness i was wrong, perhaps we can say $P(Y_1=1 \cap Y_2=1 \cap ... \cap X_n=1 )=P(Y_1=1)P(Y_2=1) \cdot ... \cdot P(Y_n=1)$ for n witnesses. If each has say probability of $P(Y_i=1)=0.9$, then we have probability of all witnesses being right of $0.9^5=0.59049>0.5$

Comment: @Tony Hellmuth. Thank you very much. If I may tax your patience just a little more, what is the probablity of all witnesses being wrong ? Final question, I promise. Best- GT

Comment: You can ask me anything you want! It's why I'm here :) So essentially, our random variable $Y_i$ takes value 0 if the witness is wrong. Similar to above we find $P(Y_1=0 \cap Y_2=0 \cap ... \cap X_n=0 )=P(Y_1=0)P(Y_2=0) \cdot ... \cdot P(Y_n=0)$. Again assuming probability of each witness being right is $P(Y_i=1)=0.9$ then $P(Y_i=0)=1-P(Y_i=1)$ under our definition of $Y_i$. So we get $0.1^5$ which is 1 in 100,000. However this will not be the case. Usually we want a scenario where we want to know the probability that at least one of them is right. $P(Y_1=1 \cup Y_2=1 \cup ... \cup X_n=1 )$

Comment: @Tony Hellmuth. Many thanks indeed. Best : GT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real difficulty with this problem is to find the appropriate way to model this question to fit the idea of "reliability".

Let $\{Y_i\}$ be a sequence of Bernoulli random variables indicating eyewitness testimony. Let $X$ be a Bernoulli random variable indicating whether or not the event in question happened. Suppose that without any eyewitness testimony, we would assume it had happened with probability $q$.

Clearly $\{Y_i\}$ are not i.i.d. because they are all jointly influenced by whether or not the event in question happened. However, we can assume that they are conditionally independent given $X$. That is, once we know that the event happened, the witnesses all choose to lie about the event or tell the truth about it independently.

So now let's define reliability. Roughly speaking, reliability is a measure of how likely a given person's statement is to be true. In reality, they could be more or less reliable for any number of reasons. In this case, let's say each eyewitness either lies or tells the truth. Furthermore, they tell the truth with probability given by the reliability assigned to them (.2,.3,.3,.4 and .4 respectively). Suppose $Y_i$ has reliability $p_i$. Then in mathematical notation, this boils down to

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_i = j|X=j) = p_i \text{ for } j \in \{0,1\}$$

Now we can do some simple Bayesian statistics.

$$\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y_1=\cdots=Y_n=1) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1=\cdots=Y_n=1|X=1)\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=1)}{\sum_{j=0}^1 \mathbb{P}(X=j)\mathbb{P}(Y_1=\cdots=Y_n=1|X=j)} = \prod_{i=1}^np_i\frac{q}{q\prod_{i=1}^np_i + (1-q)\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)}$$

Let's go back to the original question. Since there was no information regarding $X$, we can probably assume that $q=1/2$. Plugging everything in,

$$\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y_1=\cdots=Y_5=1) = 0.02$$

So it was very likely that the event did not happen. Why is this? Keep in mind that an eyewitness that was equally likely to tell the truth or lie would have a reliability of $0.5$. These eyewitnesses with reliability below 0.5 are more likely to lie than tell the truth. If several of them all claim an event happened, then it probably didn't.

Just to test our model out, now assume all five witnesses are assigned a reliability of 0.6. Then,

$$\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y_1=\cdots Y_5=1) = 0.88$$

So when eyewitnesses are even slightly more likely to tell the truth than lie, the fact that five of them agree it happened adds significant weight. In this case, we can now say $X$ happened with probability 0.88.

Comment: Good answer, but the assumption of conditional independence of the eyewitnesses' testimony should be carefully scrutinized in any real world  situation.  There are many ways it might fail.